# Fastest method for file transfer with PHP

Tags: php, file-transfer, scp

So I have workflow which transfers many files from one server to another and I wanted to see what the best way would be. Currently I am using PHP exec function to pass a SCP command to transfer a file from one server to another but I wanted to see if there is a better method that can reduce the time?

What's the speed difference between SCP vs. `file_get_contents`? The files being transferred are not too large but at times they do get fairly large (up to maximum of 2GB) so I need to be able to support all sizes.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The current command being used is:

```
exec('scp -i ......)
```

The goal is to speed up the processing time for transfering the file from one server to another. As far as the server specs, I dont have the specific steps but I know they are linux servers 32CPU with over 500GB (the servers are really optimized)

Comment: When you want to optimize something - it means that you want to improve some performance aspects. What actually doesn't fit the requirements in the current solution? What you want to improve? What your system is capable for improving?

Comment: btw you also have this function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-recv.php

Comment: this guy seems to have tested it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php#82927

Comment: @fablife: I wouldn't believe those numbers

Comment: @zerkms fair enough. Performance measurements are a science of its own.

Comment: "linux servers 32CPU with over 500GB" --- and how this is related to the network transfer speed? Do you have your network cable connected directly to CPU or consuming the whole core when performing a network transfer?

Comment: Like i mentioned i dont know every detail of the server set up i just gave what i know.

Comment: @Yeak: so what kind of answer you're looking for? You want to optimize something that you don't know? It doesn't work. When you want to optimize something - you need to find what exactly is slow first.

Comment: @fablife im gonna actually give it a try and see the comparison

Comment: @Yeak: "gonna actually give it a try" --- it is silly to try random things until you have measured the performance at first place. How will you compare the results?

Comment: @zerkms the answer im looking for is if there is another command or function our there that has some performance increase as far as file transfer goes regardless of the server set ups.

Comment: @zerkms doesnt look like youve mentioned anything useful so its not silly to give it a try. Its called testing. The way ill do it is run the same file through using the current call and run it through using the method that fablife mentioned

Comment: @Yeak: " doesnt look like youve mentioned anything useful" -- the first rule of thumb for perfomance optimization: measure and find a bottle neck. Then optimize it. Have you find it already?